# Dynamic values not submitted from form

Tags: angular, forms

I am working on Angular code.

If I manually enter values in form fields and submit the form, I get all the values in the component function.

But if I dynamically display values in form field like `value='{{detail_id}}'`, the component does not collect any value.

**component function**

```
public updateSetting(obj:any) :any {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

**template**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="updateSetting({'uname':uname, 'upwd':upwd, 'id':id})">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='uname' name='uname' class="form-control" value='{{detail_uname}}'>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name='upwd' [(ngModel)]="upwd" class="form-control" value='{{detail_upwd}}'>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)]='id' class="form-control" value='{{detail_id}}'>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
</form>
```

The values appear dynamically on form field, on click on view button in list

**button on list**

```
<a (click) = "view({'id':x.id})">View</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use value, ngModel is for storing showing values.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]='detail_uname' name ='uname' class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)] = 'detail_id' class="form-control">
```

please note that `detail_id` must be defined on ts side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using value but what about :

```
[value]="detail_uname"
```

Comment: i am using value to display  dynamic data on form.

Comment: don't use value. check my answer please.

Comment: worked , after using [value]="detail_uname" , i passed 'detail_uname'  parameter in submit

Comment: It works but it may break your form logic. what if ngModel changes? anyway you will understand what I mean with hard way :)

Comment: yes it is breaking. Got form values  by using  above logic , but  when i modify form values i am not get the modified values but the old values